# WPF FolderBrowserDialog using MVVM(without code behind)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Explanation:
I have to get FolderBrowserDialog Box once I click the browse button. And In FolderBrowserDialog Box,if I select any folder and click ok,that particular folderpath along with foldername should be shown in the textbox which is beside the browse button....But I didn't get anything once I click Browse button.
Please check my code and correct me...

**View.xaml** :

```
<Window....  xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:myproject.myViewModel"
...  >
<Window.DataContext><VM:myViewModel/>
<Grid>...
<TextBlock  Text="Folder to save files"  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<TextBox   Text="{Binding Path=FoldernameWithPath  , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"   Height="26"    IsReadOnly="True"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"    Width="150"    />
 <Button      Content="Browse"    Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  MinWidth="45"  Command="{Binding OpenFolderCommand}" />
</Grid>
</window>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
    public ICommand OpenFolderCommand
    {
        get => new RelayCommand(a => this.OpenFolder(), p => CanOpenFolder());
    }
    private string _foldernameWithPath;
    public string FoldernameWithPath
    {
        get { return _foldernameWithPath; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _foldernameWithPath)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                _foldernameWithPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FoldernameWithPath");
            }
        }
    }
    public bool CanOpenFolder()
    {
        return true;
    }
    private void OpenFolder()
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog openFolderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (openFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && OpenFolderCommand.CanExecute(openFolderDialog.SelectedPath))
        {
            OpenFolderCommand.Execute(openFolderDialog.SelectedPath);
            FoldernameWithPath = openFolderDialog.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try leaving out your CanOpenFolder. I dont see sense to validate this command parameter. When i try your code, button is disabled because of this.

Comment: Now I edited Viewmodel.cs ...But still I'm not getting

Comment: Remove 'CommandParameter="{x:Type views:myView}' this and then try,

Comment: ok I removed..But stil not getting expected output

Comment: Faisal is right, there is no need for the CommandParameter, but I don't think, that this is the reason for the behavior. I would try to set the command property as public get and private set and instanciate it in constructor or initialize method.

Comment: Malior isn't right. CanOpenFolder returns true, so that this couldn't be the reason for that.

Comment: Already I'm using INotifyPropertyChanged for my other controls, So have written as myviewmodel:INotifyPropertyChanged.....Now how should I write that particular line, if I want to use BindableBase also..

Comment: You don't need to Notify the command Property when instanciating it in constructor there is no change at runtime.

Comment: I added bindable class as well. It is copied from some Microsoft source code,

Comment: Sure it is useful. But for command properties not required. You instanciate them once maybe in constructor and usually don't change them at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changes,

In View.xaml

```
<Button Content="Browse" Command="{Binding OpenFolderCommand}"/>
```

In ViewModel.cs

```
public bool CanOpenFolder()
{
    return true;
}

private void OpenFolder()
{
    FolderBrowserDialog openFolderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (openFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && OpenFolderCommand.CanExecute(openFolderDialog.SelectedPath))
    {
        //OpenFolderCommand.Execute(openFolderDialog.SelectedPath);
        FoldernameWithPath = openFolderDialog.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this and it works. You had a bug in your code. Commands calls itself again and again,

Comment: That's right, but the call is only after ShowDialog() so that the dialog window anyway should open first. And that doesn't as he wrote.

Comment: I removed  'CommandParameter="{x:Type views:myView}' from the view. I believe he was getting some error due to this,

Comment: Don't think so. This is purely a typeof(myView) so that the command parameter (object) takes this Type and should not result in an error because he don't use it in any case.

Comment: Yeah... It works for me  but how to make the "selected  folderpath along with foldername" visible in textbox which is beside browse button @Faisal Hafeez

Comment: You can use openFolderDialog.??? to get whatever you want, `FoldernameWithPath = openFolderDialog.SelectedPath;`

Comment: @fhnaseer  If you think my question is really understandable to answer ...please vote my question

Answer (score 1):

You should not call the command from the delegated method (`OpenFolder()`). The command does nothing else than to execute the delegated method when Execute is called, which is done automatically when you click the button.

Also `ICommand.CanExecute()` is typically called automatically by WPF itself and based on the result in only enables, resp disables the button. You rarely call the CanExecute by yourself in ViewModel. In your case, you want the button always enabled, so you can skip CanExecute, or use `p => true` expression.

This should work

xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FoldernameWithPath}" IsReadOnly="True" />
<Button Content="Browse"  Command="{Binding OpenFolderCommand}" />
```

viewmodel:

```
public ICommand OpenFolderCommand {get;} = new RelayCommand(p => OpenFolder());

private string _foldernameWithPath;
public string FoldernameWithPath
{
    get { return _foldernameWithPath; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _foldernameWithPath) return
        _foldernameWithPath = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FoldernameWithPath");
    }
}

public void OpenFolder()
{
   FolderBrowserDialog openFolderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
   if (openFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
   {
      FoldernameWithPath = openFolderDialog.SelectedPath;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write the command like this:

```
public ICommand OpenFolderCommand { get; private set; }
public MyViewModel() 
{
    this.OpenFolderCommand = new RelayCommand(a=> this.OpenFolder(),p=> CanOpenFolder());
}
```